# Connection method from client gets stuck upon reading response from server

Tags: c#, server, tcp, client, streamwriter

I have a client and a server app.
The server starts and upon starting, it waits for a connection as usual.
The client sends its request through a Custom Class I have called SocketMessage, SocketMessage simply stores the client's username and a string containing the method the client wants to request to the server.
The server gets the SocketMessage, deserealizes it and reads the string indicating the method, from this, it chooses a method to execute based on a switch statement.

I can send a request from the client, receive it at the server and send a response, but back at the client, when trying to read the response, the client's Connect method gets locked at streamReader.ReadLine

This is the SERVER, ClientCommunication is running on a subprocess.

```
private void ClientCommunication(object cliente)
        {
            TcpClient tcCliente = (TcpClient)cliente;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcCliente.GetStream());
            StreamWriter serverStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(tcCliente.GetStream());

            while (serverOn)
            {

                try
                {
                    
                    var msj= reader.ReadLine();
                    SocketMessage<object> msjReceived= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocketMessage<object>>(msj);
                    
                    
                        SelectMethod(msjReceived.Method, msj, ref serverStreamWriter);
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    break;
                }
            }

            tcCliente.Close();
        }

public void SelectMethod(string pMethod, string pMsj, ref StreamWriter serverStreamWriter)
        {
            switch (pMethod)
            {
                case "CONNECT":
               
                    SocketMessage<string> connectMsj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocketMessage<string>>(pMsj);  
                        LogConnection(connectMsj.Entidad);
                        serverStreamWriter.Write("CONNECTED");
                        serverStreamWriter.Flush();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And this is the custom class for Client, which handles the sending of requests.

```
public string RequestConnection(string pUsername)
        {
            try
            {
                
                ipServer = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                client = new TcpClient();
                serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipServer, 16830);
               
                client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
                string serverRsp;

                SocketMessage<string> connectionRequest= new MensajeSocket<string> { Method= "CONNECT", Entity = pUsername};
                
                clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(cliente.GetStream());
                clientStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(cliente.GetStream());
                
                clientStreamWriter.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(connectionRequest));
                clientStreamWriter.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine("request SENT");
                //THIS is where it gets stuck
                serverRsp = clientStreamReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("streamReader READ " + serverRsp);
                
                return serverRsp;
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return ex.Message;
            }    
        }
```

Why is it getting stuck upon hitting `serverRsp = clientStreamReader.ReadLine();`? I know that ReadLine gets locked out until a response is received, but I'm sending the response from the server. I have confirmed that the server does receives the request and correctly logs it, but it seems the client is not able to read the related "CONNECTED" message, any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadLine()` waits for a line feed within the payload to terminate on. Where as your client is only sending a `Write()`, `WriteLine()` will append the line feed to the end of the payload thus the sever / listener knows when to stop listening for the data.

```
serverStreamWriter.Write("CONNECTED");
```